# Sort a php array in a custom order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "car_owners", it has three columns known as:

```
id  owner   cars
1   Greg    1
2   Gary    3
3   Aaron   2
4   Farb    3
5   REX     1
6   Fred    2
```

In the following code I get it into array and print it:

```
$exc = $conn->prepare("SELECT name,state from current_state");
        $exc->execute();
            while($finalResult = $exc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                        $tables[] = $finalResult;
             }
var_dump($tables);
```

once i get this into an array, **is there a way i could sort it in a custom order where i could get the out put like follows,
first the owners with 2 cars, then with 1 car and who has 3**

```
owner   cars
Aaron   2
Fred    2
Greg    1
REX     1
Farb    3
Gary    3
```

**P.S doing it from the table is not going to work, because im using a loop above the code which makes it impossible to do it from the SQL, can anybody tell me a way to do it from the php**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `usort` to sort the values. This will also sort by name if two owners have the same number of cars. I have changed the `SELECT` statement to match the given database definition.

```
$exc = $conn->prepare("SELECT owner, cars from current_state");
$exc->execute();

while ($finalResult = $exc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $tables[] = $finalResult;
}

usort(
    $tables,
    function($a, $b) {
        // If same number of cars, sort by name
        if ($a['cars'] == $b['cars']) return strcmp($a['owner'], $b['owner']);

        // If owner a has two cars, place before b
        if ($a['cars'] == 2) return -1;

        // If owner b has two cars, place below a
        if ($b['cars'] == 2) return 1;

        // Neither owner a nor owner b has two cars, sort by number of cars
        return ($a['cars'] < $b['cars']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);

foreach ($tables as $row) {
    echo $row['owner'], ' => ', $row['cars'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Aaron => 2
Fred => 2
Greg => 1
REX => 1
Farb => 3
Gary => 3
```

Comment: I wanted 'hearts' to come after 'spades' in a normal array. I used this method with the first line: if (substr($a, 0, 1) == 'h') return strcmp('t' . substr($a, 1), $b); and the last line: return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1; omitting all other lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when cars = 2 then 1
              when cars = 1 then 2
              when cars = 3 then 3
              else 4
         end
```

Comment: thanks bro but i want to sort it through the array, using php

Comment: you should use the best tool is available, and not the one you decide to use: you should trust the experience of who you're asking, @ShoGumLew

Comment: I agree that sql is the best tool for this task.  Unfortunately this answer (snippet dump) is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the array prepared from the mysql table, then you can use the following code-

```
$car_array=array(
    "Aaron"=>2,
    "Fred"=>2,
    "Greg"=>1,
    "REX"=>1,
    "Farb"=>3,
    "Gary"=>3,
    );

$sort_array=array("2","1","3");
$new_array=array();

foreach ($sort_array as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($car_array as $key1 => $value1) 
    {
        if ($value1 == $value ) 
            $new_array[$key1]=$value1;
    }   
}


print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: You can change the numbers also in the sort array if u want to change the order later.

Answer (score 1):

Consider sorting the resultset through sql itself. The sql provided by @juergen would meet the purpose. The only change I would like to do in the query is that 'add owner field in the order by clause'. Consider the below code snippet

```
select * from car_owners
order by (case when cars = 2 then 1
              when cars = 1 then 2
              when cars = 3 then 3
              else 4
         end), owner
```

This should meet the purpose and give you the resultset exactly as you needed.

Also, if you explicitly need to sort it through php then you use the php `usort()` function and sort the array writing a custom defined function.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP only, you can use uksort function to sort the array using a user-defined comparison function. The following code requires a copy of your `$tables` variable.

```
<?php
$tables2=$tables;
uksort($tables2, function($r1, $r2) use ($tables) {
    return ($tables[$r1]["cars"]%3) < ($tables[$r2]["cars"]%3);
});
print_r($tables2);
```